# Adding a Scrollbar to the WrapPanel

Tags: wpf, scroll, wrappanel

How can I add a scrollbar to the wrappanel control in WPF. Some of my controls are cutting off width wise due to the no scrollbar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ScrollViewer will be helpful for you in this situation.  Otherwise, you'll need to use the ScrollBar control and manually control what's visible.

Usage example for the scrollviewer:

```
<DockPanel>
   <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
       <StackPanel />
   </ScrollViewer >
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Of course, you can place your wrap panel inside the scrollviewer.